# How to change the width of drawer in Vaadin AppLayout

Tags: css, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

My class MainLayout extends AppLayout. I am using Vaadin 14. I added this to this class:

```
@CssImport(value = "./styles/drawer-styles.css", themeFor = "vaadin-app-layout")
```

I found 4 different solutions for this on Stackoverflow and Vaadin forum. I tested each one of these in the CSS-file drawer-styles.css. But none of them worked. How can this be solved?

Comment: If you would add the versions (or at least link them) you have tried and
failed with, we would not have to write five answers to find it out...

Comment: Solution 1: vaadin-app-layout::part(drawer) {
 width: 60px;
}





[part="drawer"],
:host([overlay]) [part="drawer"]::before {

 width: 60px;
}

Comment: Solution 2:[part="drawer"] { width: 8em  !important; }

Comment: Solution 3::host {
 --vaadin-app-layout-drawer-offset-size: 40px;
}

[part="drawer"] {
 width: var(--vaadin-app-layout-drawer-offset-size);
}

Comment: Solution 4: [part="drawer"] {
 width: 40px;
}

Answer (score 1):

T he following CSS should work in that stylesheet:

```
[part="drawer"] {
  width: whatever-you-want;
}
```

Comment: This was one of the 4 solutions I tried, but I tried it again. Then I cleared the web-cache and restarted the browser. But it did not change the width of the drawer. This is the only CSS I have for this class, so I don't think the problen is a conflict with some other CSS.

Comment: Your solution works, but some weird caching makes the changes in width not happening in IntelliJ. I have to build a new WAR-file, deploy it on a  server. then the changes in width are seen.

Comment: How can I disable this caching?

Comment: Can't help you with IntelliJ stuff, sorry.